# Shiny: updateCheckbogGroupInput not updating as expected

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing a shiny application to help certain people in my lab explore data produced by our instruments.  We want to have a certain set of inputs adjusted for common and known conditions, and so I've added a set of radio buttons giving the condition options.  Users can select the condition they are interested, and then the `update*` functions are used to change the inputs on the user interface to the appropriate values.

So far everything is working fine until I try to use `updateCheckboxGroupInput`.  I can't seem to get the checkbox groups to update as expected.  Does anyone else observe the same, and can you see what I've coded incorrectly?

ui.R

```
shinyUI(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("ctrl_gen_customDefault",
                   "User Defined Defaults",
                   c("System Defaults" = "none",
                     "Condition A" = "conditionA")),
      checkboxGroupInput("ctrl_gen_challengenumber",
                         label = "Challenge Number",
                         choices = c("First" = 1,
                                     "Second" = 2,
                                     "Third" = 3),
                         selected = 1:3)
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, clientData, session){
    observe({
      if (input$ctrl_gen_customDefault == "conditionA"){
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                             "ctrl_gen_challengenumber",
                             label = "Challenge Number",
                             choices = c("First" = 1,
                                         "Second" = 2,
                                         "Third" = 3),
                             selected = 2)
      }
    })
  }
)
```

Ideally, when you check the radio button for condition A, the checkbox group input for "Challenge Number" should change to only "Second" selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values generated by `checkboxGroupInput` are strings and to match these you have to pass a character vector to `selected`:

```
updateCheckboxGroupInput(
  session,
  "ctrl_gen_challengenumber",
  label = "Challenge Number",
  choices = c("First" = 1,
              "Second" = 2,
              "Third" = 3),
  selected = "2")
```

Comment: Always so simple.  Thanks!